# SSRS Font Displays Differently in Chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a chart in a dashboard I am creating.

I have been using the **Calibri** font (my bad).

The font in the chart looks different from the font in the tables and text boxes.

[image]

I added the textbox on top with the same font, weight and size to see the difference.

Is there someway to make them look the same? Arial doesn't look so blocky in a chart.

Or a way to determine which fonts render normally in a chart?

Comment: This is often caused by not setting a background color.

Comment: @Kidiskidvogingogin - unfortunately, adding a background color didn't help. :sad face:  It did sound like it might actually work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this occurs is because that chart is being rendered as an image. The font choice and size impacts the differences between the image and the browsers interpretation of the chosen font. You might be able to adjust the weight and or make a bolder section to hide the difference. Sticking with true type fonts is usually a safe bet.